# $(window).scroll function do only one time

Tags: jquery

Hello I have this script and I want that

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

    var FromTop = $(window).scrollTop(); //scroll margin from top
    var RightWrapper = $('.right_wrapper').height(); // Right wrapper height

    var Margin = false;

    var ConentHeight = $('.content_wrapper').height() + RightWrapper; //content height

    if(FromTop > 125 && RightWrapper < 500){
        $('.right_wrapper').addClass('right-fixed-top');
        Margin = true;
    }else{
        $('.right_wrapper').removeClass('right-fixed-top');
    }

    if(Margin){ // <<<<<<PROBLEM IS HERE each scroll 
        $('.content_wrapper').css({height:ConentHeight+'px'});
    }

});
```

`$('.content_wrapper').css({height:ConentHeight+'px'});` only first time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the value of `Margin` to `false`:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

    var FromTop = $(window).scrollTop(); //scroll margin from top
    var RightWrapper = $('.right_wrapper').height(); // Right wrapper height

    var Margin = false;

    var ConentHeight = $('.content_wrapper').height() + RightWrapper; //content height

    if(FromTop > 125 && RightWrapper < 500){
        $('.right_wrapper').addClass('right-fixed-top');
        Margin = true;
    }else{
        $('.right_wrapper').removeClass('right-fixed-top');
    }

    if(Margin){
        $('.content_wrapper').css({height:ConentHeight+'px'});
        Margin = false;
    }

});
```

Comment: Or make `Margin = false;`.